# Why is WPS execute process in Geoserver producing this error?

Tags: geoserver, zonal-statistics, wps

I am trying to compute **raster zonal statistics** using a TIFF and a Shapefile. I am using WPS process extension for GeoServer. I am trying to use the WPS request builder provided by my GeoServer installation under demos.

I am trying to execute the process to see the output but I am getting the message in the second screenshot. My geoTiff file is 459 MB. Am I doing something wrong?

The following are the screenshots:

[image].

[image]

The following is the xml output generated by clicking the "Generate xml from process I/O":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>data</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>soil_system:PI</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-128.14691380352517 22.714877523496572</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>-65.08558771879018 51.75931655065378</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>zones</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:soil_system="soil_system">
            <wfs:Query typeName="soil_system:USA_States_WGS84"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classification</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body/>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>statistics</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Comment: please ask for the XML and then add that to the question

Comment: @iant I just did. Thanks for taking a look at it :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to take a look at this problem @iant

Answer (score 2):

The XML contains an invalid element bit:

`<wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classification</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body/>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>`

I don't know if the process really needs it (it does not seem to be mandatory), but it has to either be populated or removed entirely.

Seems like a bug in the process builder UI, feel free to report it at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary